# Как реализовать возможность использования кириллицы в Username при использовании функции WP wp_create_user()

Tags: wordpress

Как реализовать возможность использования кириллицы в Username при использовании функции WP wp_create_user().
Сразу отмечу, что плагин Allow Cyrillic Usernames не помогает при регистрации пользователей через эту функцию.
То есть, плагин помогает, и ошибки не возникает, но пользователь не регистрируется, а функция возвращает не ошибку, а 0, как id пользователя.

Comment: Зачем вам логин на кириллице?

Comment: А [код плагина](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/allow-cyrillic-usernames/trunk/allow-cyrillic-usernames.php) посмотреть не судьба? Но согласен с пред комментатором - кириллица в логинах зло.